# Creating Groups with Specific Parameters

Tags: r

I am fairly new to R. I do most of my data prep in SQL and then link it to R for certain workflows. I would like to use R to help with my current project.

I have a data set of loans and I need to create a subset with specific requirements.

The subset should have three groupings of credit scores with specific proportions for each of the three groups. (700+ - 40%; 699-670 - 45%, 669-640 - 15%)

The three groups must have a maximum of 10% used auto loans, and cannot have more than 70% of recreational loans.

Additionally the three groups must be randomly selected and total a current balance of $40MM...

I am completely lost and would appreciate a direction. Syntax or whatever you think might be a good resource.

```
LoanID AccountZip OpenDate LoanCreditScore     LoanType LoanBalance
1  78513      53514 1/1/2014             750    Used Auto       25000
2  64684      49011 2/2/2014             699 Recreational        7500
3  94513      49011 1/1/2016             650     New Auto       50000
```

The desired output would be a data frame with all the data fields passed through

Comment: please add some data using `dput(your_data)` for instance. An expected output would also be helpful.

Comment: Does my edit help? Sorry for the lack of etiquette

Comment: You can use `?ifelse()` for the grouping, and a `?while()` and `?sample()` approach for the selection by chance.

Comment: Another route is to use `cut` to get categories, then use and `*apply` to loop through the categories, and select a specific number of rows with that category (`which` output fed to `sample`). Finally subset on the row numbers.

Comment: @lmo I have cut and created bins for the credit score. Could you provide an example of how I might use *apply? I did some research and I am not coming up with a direct application..